# Create Iterator for TFRecord dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I have multiple TFRecord datasets which I want to merge. This means, that each of these datasets contains a feature, which I want to merge into one single TFRecord, which contains all the features.

Iterating over all datasets and extracting the feature for each record, finally writing a new record containing all features, works but I have some struggle creating an efficient script.

Briefly, my problem:

The code below works.

```
tfrecord = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("/my/file.tfrecord")
for record in tfrecord:
    #extract feature
```

But the code below gives me an error.

```
tfrecord = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("/my/file.tfrecord")
iterator = iter(tfrecord)

item = iterator.next()
print(item)
```

```
Error:
.../python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 544, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eager_mode'
```

Yet, the funny thing is it does print the first record, just that it also throws an error.

I really just want an iterator object so I can iterate over the dataset by using the next() function instead of a for loop.
I hope some of you are able to help me :)

Comment: For others that want to operate on the records of a `TFRecordDataset`, you can also call the method `as_numpy_iterator()` of a Dataset object to get an iterator with nested tf.Tensors converted to nested np.arrays

Answer (score 1):

Solution found: Update tensorflow